# Is it possible to change background color of PDF in python FPDF?

Tags: python, fpdf

I am tring to create a pdf with a colored background in python using FPDF.

Is there a way to change the background color from white to some other color? Or do I have to insert colored cells to fill the entire pdf?

```
from fpdf import FPDF

pdf = FPDF()
pdf.add_page()
pdf.set_font("Arial", size=12)
pdf.set_fill_color(248,245,235)
pdf.cell(200, 40,'Colored cell', 0, 1, 'C', fill=True)
pdf.output("test.pdf")
```

Answer (score 6):

You may instead add a colored image file on to the pdf page that you have created then, add the text on to same page.

Like example:
create a new image file using Pillow package.

```
from fpdf import FPDF
from PIL import Image

pdf = FPDF()
pdf.add_page()

# creating a new image file with light blue color with A4 size dimensions using PIL
img = Image.new('RGB', (210,297), "#afeafe" )
img.save('blue_colored.png')

# adding image to pdf page that e created using fpdf
pdf.image('blue_colored.png', x = 0, y = 0, w = 210, h = 297, type = '', link = '')

# setting font and size and writing text to cell
pdf.set_font("Arial", size=12)
pdf.cell(ln=200, h=40, align='L', w=0, txt="Hello World", border=0,fill = False)
pdf.output("test.pdf", 'F')
```

Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

you can try this solution

```py
from fpdf import FPDF


pdf = FPDF()
pdf.add_page()

pdf.set_fill_color(r=150,g=0,b=0)

pdf.rect(h=pdf.h, w=pdf.w, x=0, y=0, style="DF")

pdf.output('tuto2.pdf')
```

Answer (score -2):

the best solution I have tried is the **pdfplumber** framework and here is the solution:

```
import pdfplumber
with pdfplumber.open(r'D:\examplepdf.pdf') as pdf:
     first_page = pdf.pages[0]
     print(first_page.extract_text())
```